# Nextcloud Web App hosted on Nginx has incredible slow TLS handshake

Tags: nginx, ssl, nextcloud

I’m self-hosting a Nextcloud instance. I updated this for years and was always very happy with it. I don’t use docker but hosting bare metal on a Debian 11 Bullseye system. For SSL, I use Let’s Encrypt, Webserver is NGINX. Hardware is quite good, 16 GB RAM, Xeon Dual Core, SSD.

I found out, that always the first connection attempt is veryyy slow. Afterwards, things getting better. But after a few minutes of waiting, it’s slow again.

I could reproduce this behavior with curl

```
$ curl -v https://cloud.example.org
*   Trying 2001:....:443...
*   Trying 192.168.170.11:443...
* Connected to cloud.example.org (192.168.170.11) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=cloud.example.org
*  start date: Nov 26 16:41:45 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 24 16:41:44 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cloud.example.org" matched cert's "cloud.example.org"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55f65608ee80)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: cloud.example.org
> user-agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

LONG WAITING TIME HERE (40+ seconds)

* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 302 
< server: nginx
< date: Mon, 09 Jan 2023 15:02:09 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< location: https://cloud.example.org/login
< expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< set-cookie: oc_sessionPassphrase=xxxx; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< set-cookie: oca19nuvojkz=0a58ikqc0mvt2cchvemee08vd5; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-d0dqRGNyd3ZaL1BycTh3SE1tRmw2VnArdnQvU3ZtRTlaeDlrQ0VpYnk4cz06dVYrNkt2bE9Fb0dlenI5Q0F3NVd1ejRjL1l5LytBeGtCRmNKZXcvUHNvZz0='; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; img-src * data: blob:; font-src 'self' data:; media-src *; connect-src *; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self';
< set-cookie: __Host-nc_sameSiteCookielax=true; path=/; httponly;secure; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2100 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=lax
< set-cookie: __Host-nc_sameSiteCookiestrict=true; path=/; httponly;secure; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2100 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=strict
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;
< referrer-policy: no-referrer
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-download-options: noopen
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
< x-robots-tag: none
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< 
* Connection #0 to host cloud.example.org left intact
```

So, as you see its waiting for multiple seconds on TLS handshake. What could cause this?

I’m running the latest version of Nextcloud, 24, but this problem exists for 4 or six months now. I got no response on Nextcloud forums but I consider this as Nginx / TLS problem.

Comment: Does it have enough entropy?

Comment: Try `tcpdump` and check packets timestamps.

Comment: I hoped there would be an easier answer than dumping the traffic. Never worked with dumps before.

Comment: Entropy should be sufficient `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
256`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason, in the NGINX error log. There were many errors regarding ssl and ciphers. It seems I restricted ciphers too much so clients needed a lo of time for the handshake because most of my servers ciphers was not accepted by clients.

Its possible that this happened due to an NGINX update, too.

Used [Mozillas SSL Configuration Generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) to update my config. Now, its quite fast.